# How to cover arrow functions in unit testing in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

`this.service = () => { -- statements -- }`

The above statement is to be tested using jasmine unit testing in angular.
Can i get some suggestions for that ?

`it("should service call",()=>{ // i want to call the arrow function here like component.service.? what to use in place of '?'. })`

Comment: `component.service()`

Comment: **Not Working** Option's Available : call, bind, apply ,....

Comment: Should be working, Please note the removed dot => `.`. Not `component.service.()`, just `component.service()`

Comment: `this.service.fun = () => {}` and now i want to call fun

Comment: and now it throughs error `fun is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a function so you call it immediately:

example:

```
 interface Service {
   fun: () => string;
 }

 class Component {
   constructor() {
     this.service = () => {
       return {
         fun: () => 'hello'
       };
     };
   }
   service: () => Service;
 }
```

Calling it:

```
 const component = new Component();
 const service = component.service();
 const message = service.fun();
 
 // or in one line:
 const message = new Component().service().fun();
```

[Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQkSwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgGV4DcxuAN4BQopCArhAFzAAUAlMALwB8wAzlHJAOYDcJUgF8ig0CgA2Sdu2ABhAPYBbAA4KIMaITGkU6znHIooCuA22lLUABZh2AOnY486JnUasLly3BhRycBBe3pYU1O7MbADk1jASEgpROiFCAiEgqckZWRzOaDTmnlhwuGhpwqKWehCcwHqq6ppQzMAaAO7yymoa0Azl4vrNTiUuLfXdTY55MH3J1bVKMDJIPK65I2j2YbNV+goSMPYJPLSLy6v0-SDJAPQ3wKbAkA8awBKQMFRzg8Bn7CswABMLXanQaPSgDCmGxm9C2lB2uj2ByOChOfwBgMuRCAA)

Comment: Thanks, Man i got the problem.